# TransportEclipse Error: Cannot get remote repository refs. https://github.com/VicentGN/prueba3.git: cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
 
I'm a newbie using Eclipse and Egit and I want to push a local project to my Github repository.
My Eclipse version is 4.9.0 and it's installed on Linux Mint 19 running on VirtualBox.
Any idea?
 
Thanks in advance.
[picture-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnlpo.png)

Comment: can you post a screen shot both the details clicked and the output after clicking the show error log. Also can you confirm that teh url is correct? Have you created a repo on github with that name?

Comment: Yoghesh_D There's no more details about the error. I only get "Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs". The online repository is created and the URL is correct...

Comment: hi @VicentGN what do you see in the error log?